# Angularjs : server side templating

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am very new to MEAN. And I have made an application using node.js, express and mongodb. I want to send username to dashboard after user is logged in. How can I do it using Angularjs. I don't want to use ejs templating engine. If any Middle ware is required....plzz tell me.
thank you...

this is my usercrud.js

```
var User = require("../../schema/user/userschema");

var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

const userOperation={

    login(userObject,response){
               var   username=userObject.userid;
               var   psw = userObject.password;
               User.find({ userid:username}, function (err, user)  {
                if (err) {

                     return done(err); }
                if (!user) {

                  return done(null, false, { message: 'no user found' });

                }
                if(user){

                    console.log("user's true password is: "+user[0].password);
                    console.log("password"+psw);
                    bcrypt.compare(psw, user[0].password, function(err, res) {

                    if (err){
                    throw err;}
                    if(!res) {

                      console.log('Ooops!. Wrong Pass!');
                      return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Oops! Wrong password.')); // create the loginMessage and save it to session as flashdata
                    }
                    if(res){

                       response.redirect('dashboard');
                    }
                  });
                }
              });
            },
        }
```

**how can I send username to the dashboard.html**

this is userroute.js

```
router.get('/dashboard',(req,response)=>{

});
```

Comment: Do you mean - send back just the username and have Angular update it  in the page? If so, you should read up on Angular expressions and how they are used in templates: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression

Comment: I mean how can I redirect the user to the dashboard with the username dynamically..

Comment: If you have further information, please change the question. Also, it's highly recommended to include the relevant part of your code and show what you've attempted so far.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using MEAN stack for your application, what you can do is check login via async call and return user object in response. Then you can store that user into localstorage.

Once user is successful in logIn and you get this "user" object in response, redirect user from login to dashboard using angular redirection not from back-end server.

After redirection use localstorge for getting user information.